# How to handle close tab in eclipse RCP 4

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I want make a validation when pulse close button of tab in eclipse RCP 4 application and if some validation fails then prevent de close.

Comment: Is this an e4 RCP using the application model or a 3.x compatibility RCP?

Comment: I'm using e4 Application Model

Comment: Do you just want to know about a part closing or are you trying to prevent the close?

Comment: I'm trying to Prevent the close

Comment: I haven't found anything. You can use an `ISaveHandler` but this only works if the part is dirty.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `part.setDirty(true)` together with an `ISaveHandler` like greg-449 montioned, you could listen to the model events and correct things there. Something in the direction of this:

```
public class PreventCloseAddon {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(final IEventBroker eventBroker, final EPartService partService) {
        EventHandler tbrHandler = new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                if (!UIEvents.isSET(event))
                    return;
                Object element = event.getProperty(UIEvents.EventTags.ELEMENT);
                if (element instanceof MPart) {
                    MPart part = (MPart) element;
                    if (!part.isToBeRendered()) {
                        // ... validate here ...
                        part.setToBeRendered(true);
                        partService.activate(part);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        eventBroker.subscribe(UIEvents.UIElement.TOPIC_TOBERENDERED, tbrHandler);
    }
}
```

You should be aware that the part will be rendered again with this code.

Comment: Unfortunately calling `setToBeRendered` in this event doesn't work.

Comment: I changed my code above to make it “work” as you would expect by using `EPartService` to activate the part again after setting `toBeRendered` to true. You can click on the `x` of the part, but it will not close. This makes no practical sense of course, but is a good example on what you could do.